# IE6 - custom tags without namespaces

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Is it possible in Internet Explorer 6 - yes, IE6 :( - to use custom tags without defining namespaces.

Example:

```
<!-- NS is namespace -->
<html XMLNS:NS>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        NS/:myTag {
            color: #666;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <NS:myTag>
        The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    </NS:myTag>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to use tags without `NS:` prefix in source code.

**A:** Is it possible in IE6 to use custom tags without namespaces?
**B:** If not, can I insert prefix with JavaScript in all tags with given parent?

Comment: Well, did you try it? Very few people actually have a copy of IE6 lying around these days

Comment: Yes, I tried, without namespace - it didn't works. I thought maybe some doctype can give this possibility. I didn't try with JS, now in search how to do it. Yes IE6 very rare (fortunately) these days. Maybe I need time machine.

Comment: Is it really necessary to support IE6? Once things get so old, we normally drop support for them. I wouldn't waste time on it, the user needs to upgrade. I bet 80% of the internet looks broken to any IE6 user today.. Unless it's necessary (like for private, in house, uses) I wouldn't even bother.

Comment: I do not touch IE6 many years :) It's not customer wish or ours, it's constraint. The end users (enterprise) are across the country and we can't provide quick update (many months) and do not have any access to their PCs,  users can't update machines because they do not have administration privileges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older versions of IE require that you use `createElement` at least once with the custom element name prior to styling or parsing them; it's fine if you then just throw away the element you created, the act of creating it says to IE "this is a type of element." Also, the `/` your selector should be a `\`:

```
<!-- NS is namespace -->
<html XMLNS:NS>
<head>
<script>
document.createElement("NS:myTag");       // <====
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
        NS\:myTag {                       /* <==== */
            color: #666;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <NS:myTag>
        The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    </NS:myTag>
</body>
</html>
```

The above works in IE6 (I happen to have an old VM I keep around with IE6 on it; thankfully haven't had to fire it up in months before this question).

Caveat: I'm not massively au fait with namespacing in HTML (never had the need), so apologies if the above is naive on some point. As I say, it functions in IE6 (and Chrome 42.)

---

Re your comment:

> My goal is to use in HTML `<myTag>` and not `<NS:myTag>`, because with namespace I can't simply put xml in html.

I'm confused: If you want to use `<myTag>...</myTag>`, why does the question use `<NS:myTag>...</NS:myTag>`?

But if you want to just use `<myTag>`, it works just fine — again with IE6, you'll need the `createElement`:

```
<!-- NS is namespace -->
<html XMLNS:NS>
<head>
<script>
document.createElement("myTag");
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
        myTag {
            color: #666;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <myTag>
        The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    </myTag>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In IE6 which I'm using, css works without script when used <NS:myTag> and styles NS\:myTag {}.  All tags gets from xml and I want simply put they in html and customize with css. Maybe I did missing something from your answer. My goal is to use in HTML <myTag> and not <NS:myTag>, because with namespace I can't simply put xml in html.

Comment: @Sonique: I'm confused: If you want to use `<myTag>...</myTag>`, why does the question use `<NS:myTag>...</NS:myTag>`? In any case, I've updated the answer. It's the same thing, you just don't include the namespace.

Comment: In first line I wrote "to use custom tags without defining namespaces." :) Example about how it works in IE6 now. Without namespace, I cannot customize elements. Sorry if my question misleading.

Comment: @Sonique: Always best to clearly show what you're *trying* to do. Does the update not help?

Comment: Yes, this works. But this script should be run before page loaded, I have many different XML tags in many documents, I tried to get XML tags from HTML  and run __document.createElement__ on each item, but this possible only after page loaded and we have data,  IE didn't see this items if we run script this way. So I pass XML tags in JavaScript variable and run __createElement__ in for loop. Thank you!